# Console codepage set to 437 OEM but prints different character

Tags: c#, encoding, console

```
Console.WriteLine('\xc3');
```

So in OEM 437 the character at gexadecimal C3 is `├` and my console is set to 437 OEM but when I run It, it displays `A`.
why is that?
[image]

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'├'.encode( 'cp437').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'Ã'`, and those characters are  `├` (U+251C,  *Box Drawings Light Vertical And Right*) and `Ã` (U+00C3,  *Latin Capital Letter A With Tilde*). I'd guess that `Console.WriteLine('\xc3');` in _C#_ means Unicode `Console.WriteLine('Ã');` rather than any 8-bit code page…

Comment: @JosefZ , thank you for the answer but there is one other thing. I think it is 437 OEM because I am able to change the encoding by Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 and the console properties change so...
Maybe I am getting something wrong.